# REST API to fire the event of a Journey Builder

Tags: rest-api, journeybuilder

I need your help to know if there is a way to fire the event of a journey builder with multiple records using a single REST API call.
I have created a Journey Builder, retrieve the Event Definition Key (identifier for an Interaction Trigger), then I have generated the following API request:

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /interaction/v1/events
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
"ContactKey": "ID601",
"EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-759c8c5b-18dd-8d46-3515-0af2d6320749",
"EstablishContactKey": true,
"Data": {
"FirstName":"Luca",
"MobileNumber":"XXXXXX",
"Id_Contact":"id601"}
}
```

With this request we are able to inject correctly only one record and if we try to configure the request with the code described below to inject multiple records we obtain this error:

```
{
"message": "Internal Server Error",
"errorcode": 0,
"documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm"
}:

########################################################################################

Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /interaction/v1/events
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN


{
"items": [{
"ContactKey": "ID603",
"EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-759c8c5b-18dd-8d46-3515-0af2d6320749",
"EstablishContactKey": true,
"Data": {
"FirstName":"Luca",
"MobileNumber":"XXXXXX",
"Id_Contact":"ID603"}
},
{
"ContactKey": "ID602",
"EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-759c8c5b-18dd-8d46-3515-0af2d6320749",
"EstablishContactKey": true,
"Data": {
"FirstName":"Damiano",
"MobileNumber":"XXXXXX",
"Id_Contact":"ID602"}

}
]}
```

Do you know a method to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 2):

No, it only takes one record, you have to make multiple API calls.